# NodeJS sending APN to app through firebase

Tags: ios, node.js, firebase-realtime-database, apple-push-notifications

HI i want to send the APN to my app. I am successfully able to generate notifications and send them to my app.

My issue is, the server sends notification quite frequently in a chunk. I am guessing I have issues with my algorithm of the script.

**What i want to do:**

I want the notification to be sent to device every time there's a comment in a post. I want to fetch the Username and Comment explicitly from the Firebase Database.

I am attaching the server script:

```
var firebase = require("firebase");
var once = require("once");
const apn = require('apn');

var config = {
apiKey: "<key>",
authDomain: "<domain>",
databaseURL: "<url>",
projectId: "<id>",
storageBucket: "<bucket>",
messagingSenderId: "<ID>"
};
firebase.initializeApp(config);

let options = {
 token: {
    key: "<p8 file>",

    keyId: "<key>",
    teamId: "<team>"
 },
 production: false
};

  let apnProvider = new apn.Provider(options);



  // Prepare the notifications
  let notification = new apn.Notification();
  notification.expiry = Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000) + 24 * 3600; // will      expire in 24 hours from now
  notification.badge = 3;
  notification.sound = "default";
  notification.topic = "<My bundle ID>";
  notification.payload = {'messageFrom': 'me'};


 var author;
 var dtoken;
 var spotter;
 var comment;
 var database = firebase.database();



 var postref = database.ref("posts").orderByChild("gen_notif").equalTo("yes").on("value", function (snapshot) {
     var key;
     var deviceToken;
     console.log("-------------------Post Ids----------------------")
     snapshot.forEach(function (childSnapshot) {
         key = childSnapshot.key
         author = childSnapshot.val()["author"];
         console.log(key)
         var newref = database.ref("posts/" + childSnapshot.key + "/comment").on('child_added', function(snapy){
             console.log(snapy.val())
             console.log("-----------------comment Keys----------------------")
             snapy.forEach(function(s){
                 var spotuserkey = s.key
                 comment = s.val()
                 console.log(spotuserkey)
                 var spotuser = database.ref("users/"+ spotuserkey +"/credentials/name").on('value', function(spottersnap){
                     console.log("-----------------User Key-----------------------")
                     spotuser = spottersnap.val()
                     console.log(spotuser)

                     var tokenref = database.ref("device/"+author+"/token").once('value', function(snap){
                         console.log("-----------------device token---------------------")
                         deviceToken = snap.val() 
                         console.log(deviceToken)

                          notification.alert = {
                             "title": "You Got Spotted",
                             "body": spotuser + " Spot you " + comment 
                         };

                         apnProvider.send(notification, deviceToken).then( result => {
                               console.log(result["failed"][0]["response"]);
                         });


                     })//tokenref end

                 })//spotteref end

             }); //snapy forEach end

         })//newref end    

     }); //snapshot forEach end

 }); //postref end

  apnProvider.shutdown();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To initialize your app I think it would better use the serviceAccountKey file that you can download via the Firebase Console, instead of writing directly your secret key inside your code :

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');

var admin = require('firebase-admin');

var serviceAccount = require("./serviceAccountKey.json");

admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
  databaseURL: "YOUR_DATABASE_URL_GOES_HERE"
});
```

Of course you would need to replace with your own database url here, and also make sure that your serviceAccountKey.json file is inside your functions folder.

However I think you would need to restructure your database a little bit to make it easier to retrieve your ids on the server side, for example it might look like that :

```
root/
|     ....
|  
|
|___ posts/
|      |___ postID
|              |___ authorId : ...
|              |___ caption : ...
|              |___ comments
|                     |___ commentID 
|                           |___ senderId: ...
|                           |___ text: ...
|               ...
|
|
|___ users/
|      |___ userID
|              |___ name : ...
|              |___ email : ...
|              |___ notificationTokens
|                       |___ token1 : true                       
|                       |___ token2 : true
|                        ...
```

Then you could create use the function to write the notification object inside a notification node whenever there is a new write event in your comments node :

```
exports.createPostCommentedNotification = functions.database.ref('/posts/{postID}/comments/{commentID}').onWrite(event => {

   const data = event.data;

   if(data == undefined || !data.val()) { return; }

    const postID = event.params.postID; 
    const commentID = event.params.commentID; 

    const getCommentSender = admin.database().ref(`/posts/${postID}/comments/${commentID}`).once('value');

    const getPostAuthor = admin.database().ref(`/posts/${postID}`).once('value');

    return Promise.all([getCommentSender, getPostAuthor]).then(results => {

       const commentSenderData = results[0];
       const postAuthorData = results[1];

       const commentSenderId = commentSenderData.val().senderId;
       const postAuthorId = postAuthorData.val().authorId;

       if(commentSenderId == postAuthorId) { 
          return;
       };

       const notificationID = admin.database().ref().push().key;
       const timestamp = Date.now()

       const getSenderProfilePromise = admin.auth().getUser(commentSenderId);

       return Promise.all([getSenderProfilePromise]).then(results => {

            // Note that when you create a user account you would need to set the displayName of the user using the updateProfile() method, otherwise you would need to retrieve the senderName in a different way:)

            const senderData = results[0]
            const senderName = senderData.providerData[0].displayName

            var notificationData = {
             senderName: senderName,
             notificationTimestamp: timestamp
            };

            var updates = {};

            updates['/notifications/' + postAuthorId + '/' + notificationID] = notificationData;

            admin.database().ref().update(updates);

            });
      });
});
```

Then you would create another function to actually send the push notification, using your user token, whenever there is a new notification object added to the notifications node, like so :

```
exports.sendPushNotifications = functions.database.ref('/notifications/{receiverId}/{notificationId}').onWrite(event => {

  const data = event.data;

  if(data == undefined || !data.val()) { return; }

  const receiverId = event.params.receiverId;
  const notificationId = event.params.notificationId;

  const getDeviceTokensPromise = admin.database().ref(`/users/${receiverId}/notificationTokens`).once('value');

  const getMessageContentPromise = admin.database().ref(`/notifications/${receiverId}/${notificationId}/notificationType`).once('value');

  const getSenderPromise = admin.database().ref(`/notifications/${receiverId}/${notificationId}/senderName`).once('value');

  return Promise.all([getDeviceTokensPromise, getSenderPromise]).then(results => {

    const tokensSnapshot = results[0];
    const senderSnapshot = results[1];

    const sender = senderSnapshot.val()

    if (!tokensSnapshot.hasChildren()) {
      return console.log('There are no notification tokens to send to.');
    }

    const payload = {
      notification: {
        title: `${sender}`,
        body: 'Someone commented on your post',
        badge: '1'
      }
    };

    var options = {
      priority: "high",
      timeToLive: 60 * 60 * 24,
      mutable_content : true,
      content_available : true,
      category : 'reminder'
    };

    const tokens = Object.keys(tokensSnapshot.val());

    return admin.messaging().sendToDevice(tokens, payload, options).then(response => {


      const tokensToRemove = [];
      response.results.forEach((result, index) => {
        const error = result.error;
        if (error) {
          console.error('Failure sending notification to', tokens[index], error);

          if (error.code === 'messaging/invalid-registration-token' ||
              error.code === 'messaging/registration-token-not-registered') {
            tokensToRemove.push(tokensSnapshot.ref.child(tokens[index]).remove());
          }
        }
      });
      return Promise.all(tokensToRemove);
    });
  });
});
```

Well let me know if you have any questions !

Comment: This looks perfect. I made a mistake in my script though. Thanks for helping. I'll update you once I am done integrating this. Cheers mate

Comment: Awesome ! Yeah just let me know if everything works well and feel free asking me if I can help you ;) Good luck for your project !

Comment: Hey, I might have stuck on an issue. we are using cloud functions here. This doesnt seem to work for me. I am getting `Firebase config variables are not available. Please use the latest version of the Firebase CLI to deploy this function.`. Although I have already installed the firebase CLI. Am I missing something?

Comment: I am using cloud9 and it doesnt seem to install firebase CLI. Hope you got a fix for both my query

Comment: Hmm, what do you get when you type npm -v in the Terminal ?

Comment: I think that even if you're using Cloud9 you should still install firebase tools. To check if it's installed on your machine just type npm -v in your Terminal. And if it's not installed yet well you can install it by typing npm install -g firebase-tools . Just let me know if it works :)

Comment: thanks for the reply. Well I even installed it on my machine. It generates the same error as before. Running npm -v just gives me the version of npm. I am really out of ideas what to do here. Scrapping the net isn't helping too.

Comment: What files do you have inside your functions folder ? Do you have a package.json inside ? If yes, what is written inside ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154572/discussion-between-alex-and-aakash-dave).